# Running Sharepoint Server/Foundation on a 32x system - is it possible

Tags: visual-studio

I'm a Sharepoint manager, and I've recently acquired Visual Studio in the hopes of deploying some more custom solutions. However, I work in Communications, and therefore am stuck with a computer that isn't particularly powerful (32x).

I'm aware that in order to develop for SP in Visual Studio you need either Foundation or Server, but I see that it needs 64x to run.

Is there any way round this, or am I just going to have to beg for a better machine?

Thanks
C

Comment: Which sharepoint version?

Comment: Is it for 2013? If so,  you can install it only on 64 bit hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint version greater than 2010 are requires 64 bit Windows operating system.that is minimum requirement. Now you can do

1. Create a 64 bit of VM on your 32 bit of is and then install sharepoint on it
2. Or you can ask for better machine with 64 bit os